# Linear Programming : Is there any other way to solve than graphs?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, book-recommendation

In my highschool curriculum there's a a chapter on Linear Programming Problems. In the chapter there are bunch of unproved statements and mechanical ways to solve linear problem. But my question is- Is there any other way to solve them without plotting lines? Things are looking really unrigorous to me. And what book should I refer to if I want to have a better understanding of LP ?

Comment: Beyond 2 variables it is impossible to do using graphs. The most well known method for large numbers of variables is called the Simplex Method. A good background book from an applications point of view is "Introduction to Management Science" by B. W. Taylor III. This will also introduce you to many other Linear Programming problems and their solution. A more sophisticated book from a mathematical point of view is "Operations Research" by H. A. Taha.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at operations research, which is a field specializing in linear programming, or more exactly, optimization problem. In accordance with the comment above, linear programming problems with more than two variables are not possible to be solved by graphs. In operations research, we try to make use of other methods, say Simplex method. In order to fully understand the content in operations research, some knowledge in linear algebra may be needed. In fact, some of the concepts in operations research are highly related to the graphical method in two-variable LP. The book *Operations Research: an Introduction* by H.A. Taha would be a nice reference book. I hope it helps.